# Помогите получит GET запрос php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

везде работает кроме одного фала.

```
\\ловлю переменную в моем случае id
if ($_GET['id']) {$id = $_GET['id'];}

\\передаю запрос
<a href="file?id=1">Кнопка 1</a>
<a href="file?id=2">Кнопка 2</a>

\\получаю содержимое
if ($id== 1) { echo 'Показывается Кнопка 1'; } if ($id== 2) { echo 'Показывается Кнопка 2'; }
```

у меня немного иначе выходит код:

```
if ($_GET['id']) {$id = $_GET['id'];}

\\передаю запрос
<a href="file/'.$url.'?id=1">Кнопка 1</a>
<a href="file/'.$url.'?id=2">Кнопка 2</a>

\\получаю содержимое
if ($id== 1) { echo 'Показывается Кнопка 1'; } if ($id== 2) { echo 'Показывается Кнопка 2'; }

\\ и у меня в штакесе такое
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /file.php?category=$1 [L] \\ category - это таблица базы
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /file.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L] \\ это для навигации (стр 1,2,3 и тд)
```

так же в файле category ловлю GET-от чтобы вывести содержимое.
Я так понимаю это связано со штакесом?

Comment: id не отправляется. Пытался его посмотреть обычным способом echo id; его нет

Comment: Что у вас в строке url и что именно не работает? Вот после этого `if ($_GET['id']) {$id = $_GET['id'];}` какое значение лежит в `$id`?

Comment: @SwaD
Я же выше написал что $id пустое.
В строке url  адрес

Comment: Так добавьте перед id знак ``$`` чтобы получилось ``$id``